# How to invoke getter method for instance that locate inside of another instance

Tags: java, reflection

I have some classes like below:

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Person{
    @JsonProperty("cInfo")
    private ContactInformation contactInfo;
    private String name;
    private String position;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class ContactInformation{
    @JsonProperty("pAddress")
    private Address address;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class Address{
    private String street;
    private String district;
}
```

And what I am going to do is writing an Utils method for the Person object that take one parameter which is the attributeName as String and return the getter value for this attribute.

Ex:

```
attributeName = name -> return person.getName() 
attributeName = position -> return person.getPosition() 
attributeName = cInfo.pAddress.street -> return person.getContactInfo().getAddress().getStreet() 
attributeName = cInfo.pAddress.district -> return person.getContactInfo().getAddress().getDistrict()
```

Below is what I've done: I loop through all the fields in the Person object and check if the attributeName equal to either the JsonProperty's Name or the Field's Name then I will return this getter.

```
Object result;
Field[] fields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    JsonProperty jsonProperty = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(JsonProperty.class);
    if (jsonProperty != null && jsonProperty.value().equals(attributeName)) {
        result = Person.class.getMethod("get" + capitalize(field.getName())).invoke(person);
    } else {
        if (field.getName().equals(attributeName)) {
            result = person.class.getMethod("get" + capitalize(field.getName()))
                    .invoke(person);
        }
    }
}
```

This worked but only with the fields that locate direct in the Person class, ex: name, position. With the fields inside of contactInfo or address I am still getting stuck there. Can anyone give me some hint here how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#findAnnotation-java.lang.reflect.Method-java.lang.Class-  will may solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because path like `a.b.c` related to different objects. So you need to. split by point and for each token call get and use obtained result for next token

**UPDATE**: something like:

```
private static Object invkGen(Object passedObj, String attributeName) throws Exception {
    final String[] split = attributeName.split("\\.");
    Object result = passedObj;
    for (String s : split) {
        if (result == null) {
            break;
        }
        result = invk(result, s);
    }
    return result;
}

private static Object invk(Object passedObj, String attributeName) throws Exception {
    Object result = null;
    final Field[] fields = passedObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        JsonProperty jsonProperty = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(JsonProperty.class);
        if (jsonProperty != null && jsonProperty.value().equals(attributeName)) {
            result = Person.class.getMethod("get" + capitalize(field.getName())).invoke(passedObj);
        } else {
            if (field.getName().equals(attributeName)) {
                result = passedObj.getClass().getMethod("get" + capitalize(field.getName()))
                    .invoke(passedObj);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```